# Xml not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android, xml, compiler-errors, href

Why do I get an error?

```
\n<a href="https://www.facebook.com/midberg.ung?ref=ts&fref=ts">Upplýsingar um Miðberg</a>
```

[image: error]

This is in a string for a android app it does not accept the link

Comment: Since we cannot see the line, it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: _The reference to entity "fref" must end with the ";" delimiter_

Comment: If I add the ";" delimiter nothing changes except it then says "The entity "fref" was referenced, but not declared."

Answer (score 3):

The ampersand is being interpreted as an escape character. When the ampersand`&`is seen in an  XML or HTML stream it is expected to be followed by one of a few defined entities.
In this case you need to escape the ampersand itself by replacing it with`&amp;`i.e. an escape, the ampersand entity and a trailing semicolon.